# Bizzare behaviour from Amazon SQS Javascript SDK (sendMessage)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm at the end of my rope here, so I'll keep it short and simple. Here's my code sample:

```
var message = JSON.stringify(value)
var url = process.env.SQS_URL + 'ts-notifications'
services.queue.sendMessage({
    MessageAttributes: {
        "responseId": {
            DataType: 'String',
            StringValue: responseIdentifier.toString('hex', true)
        },
        "surveyId": {
            DataType: 'String',
            StringValue: surveyIdentifier.toString('hex', true)
        },
        "itemId": {
            DataType: 'String',
            StringValue: key
        }
    },
    MessageBody: message,
    QueueUrl: url,
    DelaySeconds: 0
}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        cb(err)
    } else {
        cb()
    }
})
```

Running this gets me this error:

`{ [UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'MessageAttributes' found in params]
  message: 'Unexpected key \'MessageAttributes\' found in params',
  code: 'UnexpectedParameter',
  time: Sat Jan 07 2017 20:06:33 GMT+0000 (UTC) }`

Here's a link to the AWS SQS Javascript SDK for sendMessage: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#sendMessage-property

It seems pretty clear to me that MessageAttributes is a valid parameter of sendMessage. I'm open to any and all suggestions, because this one is stumping me!

P.S., yes, I'm on the correct API version (there's only one anyway), and the variables above correspond to valid things higher up in the code.

Thanks all!

Comment: The SQS API has at least two versions, `2012-11-05` and `2009-02-01`.

Comment: What is services.queue? Any chance that it is not effectively "new require("aws-sdk").SQS()"? Anyhow, I ran essentially the same code with current SDK and current version of node and it worked fine to an SQS queue in us-east-1.